# Angular forms: Validators.email vs custom regex

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In this project, I see people use both the "built-in" validator of angular and a custom one.

The built in goes as follows:

```
this.emailForm = fb.group({
  name: [null, Validators.required],
  email: [
    null,
    {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email],
      asyncValidators: []
    }]
});
```

The custom one looks like:

```
const EMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

export class CustomValidators {
  getEmailValidator(): any{
    return Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEX);
  }
}
```

And is used in a formBuilder:

```
   this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'displayName' : [''],
      'email' : ['', [Validators.required, this.customValidators.getEmailValidator()]],
    });
```

Is there any special case where a custom (error prone) regex-wrapping validator would add value compared to the built-in angular forms one?

Comment: For us one issue was with the backend not accepting an e-mail like the inbuilt email validator was considering valid, like for example an email like `my@localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to use pattern validator to get strict email from the user.

If we use in-built validator `Validators.email`, this makes `abcd@example` a valid one.

And using the regex pattern we can customize the email validation to make it valid only when it has a complete email addres like `abcd@example.com`.

So by using pattern/custom validators, it gives us  the option to customize the validation

Please find the working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/J8ouAf?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Vikash, it makes sense now